# How to enable smooth scrolling in Opera Next (v26)?

Tags: scrolling, smoothing, opera-next

It seems, the hidden option to enable smooth scrolling in the new Opera completely disappeared. Is there a way to enable smooth scrolling in Opera Next?

Please don't suggest extensions like [Google Chrome's SmoothScroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/nbokbjkabcmbfdlbddjidfmibcpneigj) as they do not work when JavaScripts are disabled on a web page (I use this for security reasons, like the NoScrpit extension in FireFox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to launch `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\launcher.exe" --enable-smooth-scrolling`.

This works for me for Opera stable 27.0.1689.66.

Comment: Are you sure that it really works? I found this solution too and tried it earlier, a week or two ago, but it seems this command line switch did not have any effect. As I know, Opera Next is based on the Chromium engine, which no longer supports this key, so I do not understand how it can work in Opera Next...

Comment: At least this works in my environment: `Opera stable 27.0.1689.69` and `Opera next 28.0.1750.15`

Windows 8.1 64-bit

Comment: Update for `Opera Stable 30.0.1835.59`: --enable-smooth-scrolling still works.

Comment: Meanwhile 2023 it's Opera 98.x ... try opera://flags/ ... but doesn't work (sometimes)